# mount page with path to "/"

Tags: wicket

Im trying to use mountPage in wicket to mount "/" url as my MainPage url.

My WebApplication looks like this now:

```
public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication
{
@Override
public Class<HomePage> getHomePage()
{
    return HomePage.class;
}

@Override
public void init()
{
    super.init();
    mountPages();
}

private void mountPages()
{
    mountPage( "/home", HomePage.class );
    mountPage( "/about", AboutCompany.class );
    mountPage( "/prices", Prices.class );
    mountPage( "/gallery", Gallery.class );
    mountPage( "/contact", Contact.class );
    mountPage( "/offer", Offer.class );
}
}
```

and actually works great, but I'd like to change "/home" into "/", yet it messes a lot with CSS for example, not transfering it, but whole HomePage instead. How can I make this work the way I want to?

Comment: Just remove the line "mountPage( "/home", HomePage.class );".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since wicket 1.5 you can apply [HomePageMapper](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/request/mapper/HomePageMapper.html) , it is designed to map requests to root path. Actually the HomePageMapper will be applied by wicket automatically for the page provided in your `WebApplication`'s `Class<? extends Page> getHomePage()` so that your homepage will be mounted to path root