# How to mount pages in a different package in Wicket?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a wicket application (version 6.10) deployed in Tomcat7: myapp.war

web.xml has following configuration:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myapp.wicket</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myapp.MyWebApp</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myapp.wicket</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So I can access wicket pages like

```
http://myhost/myapp/pages/HomePage
```

Untill here everything works fine. I mount my pages in `MyWebApp.init()` like this:

```
mountPackage("/", HomePage.class);
```

and I am able to access HomePage as well as the other pages in the same package as specified above.

**The problem** arrives when I try to mount pages in a different package com.myapp.mobile
If I use same strategy as before, it does not work at all:

```
mountPackage("/m/", MobilePage.class);
```

When I try to access MobilePage, I get an exception:

```
http://myhost/myapp/pages/m/MobilePage

WicketObjects.resolveClass WARNING  Could not resolve class [com.myapp.m]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapp.m
```

And the same for any other page in the same package (all of them are Bookmarkable). However if I mount them one by one:

```
mountPage("/m/MobilePage", MobilePage.class);
mountPage("/m/MobilePage2", MobilePage2.class);
```

, or if I mount them in the root, it works:

```
mountPackage("/", MobilePage.class);
```

in the former case accessing them with the `myapp/pages/m/MobilePage` and in the latter without /m/ : `myapp/pages/MobilePage`

So my question here is (and sorry for long explanation): how to mount a new package under a desired path (/m/ in this case)?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10700321/176897

Comment: @tetsuo I don't want the pages as "root" pages, I want them mounted under certain path so that link doesn't help much

Comment: Ok, after a day fighting with all these stuff just found that the method should be called without last '/' so

`mountPackage("/m", MobilePage.class);`

or even

`mountPackage("m", MobilePage.class);`

works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the method with '/m/' path, do it without last slash, so

```
mountPackage("/m", MobilePage.class);
```

works just fine...

One day lost for this :(

Comment: The classname in the error message could have given you a hint: "Could not resolve class [com.myapp.m]". Notice it is saying that it is looking for a class named 'm' in package com.myapp ...

Answer (score 1):

I have personally not used this syntax, but you might try it:

```
public final void mount(String path, PackageName packageName)
```

This seems to address what you are looking for.

You would write it like this:

```
public final void mount("/m/", PackageName.forClass(MobilePage.class));
```

Regards

Comment: That method is not present in wicket 6.10 anymore